# Count cells in column C, excluding instances where Column E contains specific text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif

I would like to count the number of occasions a report has been logged (column c) in the last 50 days, excluding cases where reports have been marked as "Test" in column E.

I have a working formula for the first half, but I can't seem to get a figure out how to exclude instances where column E is marked as a "test".

=COUNT(FILTER('Report Log'!C:C,DATEDIF('Report Log'!C:C,NOW(),"D")<5000))

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to be pretty cross-compatible between Google-Docs and Excel.

```
=countifs(E:E, "<>*TEST*", C:C, ">"&(today()-50))
```

Not sure from your narrative whether that should be `..., ">="&(today()-50))`. Check the results closely to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works ?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Report Log'!C:C > TODAY()-50)*('Report Log'!E:E <> "test"))
```